# Copy data from multiple workbook's sheets (name contains "SAP") into one sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, runtime-error

I would like the merge data from worksheets where the sheet name contains "SAP". I have written some code to do this but every time it runs I get `Run-time error '438'`. This is just the beginning of my code, but it doesn't work :(

```
Private Sub MergeFiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xPath As String

    xPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Filename = Dir(xPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each ws In Workbooks(Filename)
            If LCase(ws.Name) Like "SAP*" Then
                Sheets(ws).Activate
                Range("A2:L85").Select
                Selection.Copy
            End If
        Next ws

        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Can someone help me solve this please?

Comment: First you need to set the open workbook with keyword set , you might be getting this error on the for loop !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your FOR statement with following and it should work.

You want to access the worksheets inside workbook so you need to refer the worksheets.

```
For Each ws In Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets
```

Comment: oh god, I'm so terrible :DDD didn't notice this awkward thing :D thanks for helping me